# How does pickle.load work on class objects that have been modified and saved?

Tags: python, class, pickle

Say I have four files `main_class.py`, `help_class.py`, `train.py` and `predict.py`

`main_class.py` consists of

```py
from help_class import HC

class MC:
    hc = HC()

    def fit(self):
        self.hc.fit()

    def predict(self):
        return self.hc.predict()
```

and  `help_class` has

```py
class HC:
    instances = None

    def fit(self):
        self.instances = "fitted"

    def predict(self):
        return self.instances
```

If I then in `train.py` train a `MC` instance, pickle it, and then load it in `predict.py` then `mc.predict()` now returns `None` and not `"fitted"`

```py
#train.py
from main_class import MC
import pickle

mc = MC()
mc.predict() #None
mc.fit()
mc.predict() #"fitted" 


with open("./mc_fitted.pkl","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(mc,f)
```

```py
# predict.py

import pickle

with open("./mc_fitted.pkl","rb") as f:
    mc = pickle.load(f)

mc.predict() # None
```

I think I've heard somewhere, that `pickle` does actually not save the objects per say, but more creates a "blue print" to reconstruct the data, thus it might somehow make sense that the `instances` object in `hc` is overwritten if we, some place, create a new instance of `hc`, since `instances` is a class instances and not object instances, but I'm not 100% sure when/where this happens.
I hope that someone could shed some light on exactly *why* or *when* this happens when using `pickle`?

Note, I'm aware that this can be fixed just by moving `hc = HC()` inside an `__init__` call, thus this is not a question on "how to fix this issue". I'm also aware about the difference between having objects in `__init__` and in class contructor, but I might be short on some `pickle` knowledge here